# One method fails unit test only when all tests are run but passes when tested individually?

Tags: java, unit-testing, validation, visual-studio-code, junit

I am a first year at college studying application dev and our assignment is to make a simple registration and log in system.
The only problem right now is that the unit testing doesn't work when I run them all at once with the Run Tests feature on VSCode.
the error is this

```
java.lang.AssertionError
 at st10035771.LoginTest.testIsValidPasswordF(LoginTest.java:35)
 at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
 at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
 at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
 at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
 at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
 at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
 at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
 at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
 at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
 at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
```

Login.java:

```
    package st10035771;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {
    public final static int USERNAME_LIMIT = 5;
    public final static int PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8;
     

    public static boolean checkUserName(String username) {
        return username.length() <= USERNAME_LIMIT && username.contains("_");

    }
/*
 * code attribute
 * this code was adapted from DelftStack
 * https://www.delftstack.com/howto/java/password-checker-java/
 */
    public static boolean checkPasswordComplexity(String password) {
      boolean isValidPassword;
      final int minUppers = 1;
      final int minDigits = 1;
      final int minSpecials = 1;
      int uppers = 0;
      int digits = 0;
      int specials = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            char ch = password.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))
                uppers++;
            else if (Character.isDigit(ch))
                digits++;
            //if (ch >= 33 && ch <= 47 || ch == 64) {
              if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) {
                specials++;
            }

        }

        if (password.length() >= PASSWORD_LENGTH && uppers >= minUppers && digits >= minDigits
                && specials >= minSpecials) {

            return isValidPassword = true;
        } else {
            return isValidPassword = false;
        }

    }
    public static void inputUser(){
        System.out.println("Please enter username:");
         Scanner un = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userName = un.next();

            if (checkUserName(userName)) {
                System.out.println("Username successfully captured");
            } else {
                System.out.println(
                        "Username is not correctly formatted, please ensure that your username contains an underscore and is no more than 5 characters in length.");
            }
    }

    

    public static void inputPass(){
        System.out.println("Please enter password:");
         Scanner pa = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userPass = pa.next();

            if (checkPasswordComplexity(userPass)) {
                System.out.println("Password successfully captured");
            } else {
                System.out.println(
                        "Password is not correctly formatted, please ensure that the password contains at least 8 characters, a capital letter, a number and a special character.");
            }
        
    }

    
}
```

LoginTest.java

```
package st10035771;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class LoginTest {

    public LoginTest() {
    }

    Login loginTest = new Login();

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {

    }

    @Test
    public void testCheckUserName() {
        assertTrue(loginTest.checkUserName("kyl_1"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCheckUserNameF() {
        assertFalse(loginTest.checkUserName("kyle!!!!!!!"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidPassword() {
        assertTrue(loginTest.checkPasswordComplexity("Ch&&sec@ke99!"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidPasswordF() {
        assertFalse(loginTest.checkPasswordComplexity("password"));
    }

}
```

The only one that fails when tested all at once is the `TestIsValidPasswordF`

Comment: Something in your tests is preserving state.  Make sure to clean up, shut down or reset or disable resources which were set up for each test.

Comment: static fields, static methods... Really a bad idea. Remove all that `static` things and re-run your tests.

Comment: @Stewart what do you mean by this, im only a first year student XD

Comment: @M.Deinum it was really the only thing i could do to make things work :/
so i cant really remove them without breaking everything

Comment: Which is the wrong thing... Those static fields should be local to the `checkPasswordComplexity` method and not part of your class. What happens is that your first call will set some value, as the value is static (meaning shared between instances, as they are part of the class **not** the object instance) it will keep counting. Which will fail your checks. I strongly suggest a read on static-members and non-static class members.

Comment: @M.Deinum check out the code now

Comment: Then the real answer is to step back. You are basically trying to make progress by trial and error. But that isn't a good strategy when you do not UNDERSTAND what is going on. Meaning: the difference between having "static" fields vs non-static is SUPER basic. Step back, and LEARN what this is about. Then come back to your code, and apply what you have learned. There are no detours in programming. You have to UNDERSTAND what every character in your code means and does. Adding something here or there HOPING it magically does the right thing ... isn't effective.

Comment: And note: all your methods are static. So ... there is no need at all to actually instantiate an object of the Login class. As said: super basic stuff. Stop your project, pick up a book or tutorial and LEARN that stuff. Anything else means that you are just wasting more time.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, you are correct, I actually only started understanding what I was doing 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is your uppers / digits / specials counts are never set back to zero after checking a password. So when you run all tests and it gets to `testIsValidPasswordF` I would assume `testIsValidPassword` has ran first and you already have a number greater than 1 in these counts.

When you run a test on its own the counts start as 0 which is why it passes.

Moving these counts to the start of the `checkPasswordComplexity` method should fix it.